# Norm2 of a vector of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, normed-spaces

I am migrating a matlab code into C++ and I need to know how does matlab calculate the norm of below matrix.

For two numbers, A=a+ib , B=c+id, I know I should do [(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2]^1/2. But how is it done for 3 numbers?

```
    a=[1+1i 2+2i 3+3i]
    norm(a)

    ans = 5.2915
```

Comment: Your formula for two numbers is wrong. It measures $|A-B|$ rather than the norm of the vector whose entries are $A,B$.

Comment: Note that if the above was not a $1 \times n$ matrix (or transpose), then the norm computation is not so straightforward.

Comment: Note that Matlab's `norm` does more than just take the square root of the sum of squares, complex or otherwise. In particular, it is careful to avoid overflow by using `hypot` (or a multidimensional equivalent), which may or may not be relevant to your application.

Comment: And the answer to you question is actually [right in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/norm.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (L2) norm of a complex vector $v$ is $\sqrt{\sum_i |v_i|^2}$, where $|x+yi|^2 = x^2 + y^2$. In our case, we get
$$ \|a\|^2 = |1+i|^2+|2+2i|^2+|3+3i|^2 = 1^2+1^2+2^2+2^2+3^2+3^2 = 28. $$
You can check that $\sqrt{28}\approx 5.2915$.

Comment: Very much appreciated Yuval.